# Cannot enable the javac -source=1.6 option when compilng grails app in STS using JDK 1.7 on Mac OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: grails, osx-mountain-lion, javac

Hi I am trying to create a basic app using the latest version of STS (Spring Tool Suite) and the latest Grails plugin. Then the generated app is compiled I receive an error from javac:

```
Invalid commandline usage for javac.
javac: invalid source release: 1.6
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

When I attempt to use javac from the command line (I have ensured that I am using the latest JVM 1.7.0_09 from Oracle) then I found that java does not accept values higher that 1.5 for the -source or the -target options.

How do other people work around this? When I attempt to change the grails project to 1.5 by setting the following in BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.target.level = 1.5
grails.project.source.level = 1.5
```

I receive the following error which I attribute to the libs being compiled for 1.7:

```
class file has wrong version 51.0, should be 49.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The issue was a number of jars had been installed into the /Library/Java/Extensions folder on my machine including a tools.jar from JDK 1.5 and this was being picked up before my jdk 1.7 javac.

I am not sure which past installation was responsible for this but by removing all the jars out of that directory I was able to preform 'grails compile' on my application.